# Write the boolean expression from OR-AND to AND-OR

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have an expression `(a+b'+c')(a'+b'+c)` and I am struggling to rewrite it as an AND-OR from its current OR-AND state. I started using De Morgans, but that went the wrong way quickly.

How can I make this an AND-OR using properties and theorems of Boolean algebra?

Comment: Use the distributive law. Then use the distributive law some more until there's nothing left to distribute. Finally remove terms such as $a\bar a$ which are always $0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That gives me `aa' + ab' + ac + b'a' + b'b' + b'c + c'a + c'b'+ c'c` right? Then by complement, `aa'` and `c'c` are `0`. Leaves me with `ab' + ac + b'a' + b'b' + b'c + c'a + c'b'`. But by idempotent, `b'b'` is `b'`. So I  get `ab' + ac + b'a' + b' + b'c + c'a + c'b'`.

Comment: Yes, and that's a valid DNF form. But you can make it somewhat simpler by (1) removing $a\bar a$ and $\bar c c$, (2) rewriting $\bar b\bar b$ to $1\bar b$, (3) putting all the terms that include $\bar b$ together with the $\bar b$ outside a parenthesis, and (4) letting the $1$ term _inside_ that parenthesis eat everything else.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I actually get `b'(a + a' + c + c' + 1) + ac + c'a'`, that was a typo. Leaves me with `b' + ac + c'a'`, what theorem works here??

Comment: @HenningMakholm Or can an AND-OR be more than just 2 terms so long as it is in AND-OR format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use distribution:

$$(a+b'+c')(a'+b'+c)=$$

$$aa'+ab'+ac+b'a'+b'b'+b'c+c'a'+c'b'+c'c=$$

$$0+ab'+ac+b'a'+b'+b'c+a'c'+b'c'+0=$$

$$ac+b'+a'c'$$

You could also have done:

$$(a+b'+c')(a'+b'+c)=$$

$$b'+(a+c')(a'+c)=$$

$$b'+aa'+ac+c'a'+c'c=$$

$$b'+ac+a'c'$$

Answer (score 0):

We begin with a conjunction of disjunctions (conjunctive normal form, CNF)
$$(a+b'+c')(a'+b'+c)$$

We should first notice the common disjunct $b'$
$$(a+c')(a'+c)+b'$$

Distributing the rest will then give you a disjunction of conjunctions (disjunctive normal form, DNF) as required.   Vanishing the conjoined complements ($aa', cc'$) will simplify this to a disjunction of three conjuncts.